# SVG is created every time when i come on the page onNginit()

Tags: angular

I have create svg in a component in the OnNgInit() method. When come on that page every time new svg is created.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    const margin = {top: 500, right: 50, bottom: 10, left: 500};
    const projection = d3.geoMercator();

    const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('viewBox', '210 100 800 600')
        .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMax')
        .style('max-width',  'auto')
        .style('display', 'flex')
        .style('height', '100vh')
        .style('margin', margin);
    const path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);
    const g = svg.append('g');
    g.attr('class', 'map');
```

Comment: So what is the problem? And what is expection?

Comment: basically when every time new one svg is created i want only one.

Comment: until i click on refresh page then its new one otherwise its just added o the page.

Comment: Use a service that creates and stores the SVG. Then inject the service into this component and make it use the instance that's stored inside the service.

Comment: @RaheelaAslam are you creating multiple instances of your component in which svg is created?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue mistake was on line of code `d3.select('body').append('svg')`
fixed as:
`d3.select('idOftheDiv').append('svg')`